# Azure Artifacts not working with powershell repository

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-artifacts

i have an interesting issue with Azure Artifacts and sharing a private powershell repository with it.

I followed the guidance provided in this official microsoft documentation: [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops)

I successfully packed and published the module to azure artifacts. But as soons as i try to connect with powershell to the feed i get some problems:

Register-PSRepository and Register-PackageSource are working fine. But Find-Module gives me the first error:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name "PowershellAzureDevopsServices" -SourceLocation "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v2" -PublishLocation "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v2" -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices
        
Register-PackageSource -Name "PowershellAzureDevopsServices" -Location "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v2" -ProviderName NuGet -Trusted -SkipValidate -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices
        
Find-Module -Repository PowershellAzureDevopsServices

WARNUNG: Cannot access
'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v2'. Are you
missing 'Credential' parameter in the cmdlet?
WARNUNG: Query Url
```

I then put the credential parameter to Find-Module and it showed me the modules like expected:

```
Find-Module -Repository PowershellAzureDevopsServices -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
0.0.7      Example.Module                      PowershellAzureDe... Package description
1.0.0      Get-Hello                           PowershellAzureDe... Package description
```

But when i try to install the found modules, the next error occures. This error i couldnt solve:

```
Find-Module -Repository PowershellAzureDevopsServices -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices | Install-Module -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices -Scope CurrentUser
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to find dependent module(s) (SampleDependency)
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1912 Zeichen:34
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToFindDependencyPackage,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPac
   kage

PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to find dependent module(s) (SampleDependency)
In C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1912 Zeichen:34
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SampleDependency:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToFindDependencyPackage,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPac
   kage
```

**What i also tried so far:**

- Tried to use nugetv3 urls instead of v2 `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v3/index.json`
- I also checked the packagesource and the PSRepository. Here i found interesting, that there are 2 Packagesource Providers. (Only one registered and trusted PSRepository)

Get-PackageSource

```
   Name                             ProviderName     IsTrusted  Location
    ----                             ------------     ---------  --------
    PowershellAzureDevopsServices    NuGet            True       https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...
    PSGallery                        PowerShellGet    False      https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
    PowershellAzureDevopsServices    PowerShellGet    True       https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/...
```

These 2 Providers are also showing up when executing Find-Modules in verbose mode:

```
Find-Module -Repository PowershellAzureDevopsServices -Credential $credsAzureDevopsServices -Verbose
AUSFÜHRLICH: Repositorydetails, Name = 'PowershellAzureDevopsServices', Location =
 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
AUSFÜHRLICH: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
AUSFÜHRLICH: Die angegebenen Quellnamen werden verwendet: 'PowershellAzureDevopsServices'.
AUSFÜHRLICH: Das Anbieterobjekt für den PackageManagement-Anbieter "NuGet" wird abgerufen.
AUSFÜHRLICH: Der angegebene Speicherort ist
"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v2", und
PackageManagementProvider ist "NuGet".
AUSFÜHRLICH: Total package yield:'0' for the specified package ''.
'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/myorg/myprojectid/_packaging/myfeed/nuget/v2/' for ''.
AUSFÜHRLICH: Total package yield:'2' for the specified package ''.
```

But at the end, i have no idea why i cant install the modules ? Maybe you guys have some interesting approches here ?

Some interesting links i found during my research:
[GitGub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/12293)
[MS Dev Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/impossible-to-register-an-artifacts-feed-in-a-powe/620996)

But unfortunatly none the links helped me in this case.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: PS first checks current folder for a cmdlet and then uses PSMODULEPATH environmental variable to find a cmdlet.  There is both a System and User PSMODULEPATH that is used.  You can find the paths by pressing start button and typing Edit Environmental Variables.  Either your version of PS is not compatible with the cmdlet or the PSMODULE path isn't finding all the paths.  This looks like you have a mixture of different PS versions and cmdlets.

Comment: Hi @jdweng: Thank you for your response. I checked my module path environment variable and it is %ProgramFiles%\WindowsPowerShell\Modules and %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules. So from my understanding the path for "dependent modules" should be okay here. 
Further i am using Powershell Verions 5.1. And the install-module cmdlet should be compatible with this powershell version accordion to MS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: If you are downloading make sure you specify the  download version 5 and not version 7. The download I believe will download latest in version is not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the issue that lead to that error.
First of all, to every one who wants to use azure devops artifacts to publish powershell modules, you can put the documentation to the trash: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/tutorials/private-powershell-library?view=azure-devops)

The root cause of the issue when trying to install the module, came from a wrong .nuspec file.
When you create the nuspec file like ms says, the file is full with placeholder xml tags and as long as you dont delete these tags you are unable to install the module.

The only necessary tags are:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Example.Module2</id>
    <version>$VERSIONHERE$</version>
    <authors>Jon doe</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <!-- <icon>icon.png</icon> -->
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Every other tags needs to be deleted.

So from the microsoft document, one of the first things you do (create the nuspec file) this default misconfiguration will result in a error at the last step (Install-Module).

Thankfully this guy on reddit explained the problem more detailed:
(https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/12529)